# How to access an object's instance variables while stubbing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, instance-variables

I'm writing some tests for a web application and one of the controllers calls `resolve` on a `Scope` object, which returns a slightly modified scope. In the test I would like to stub this method to return the original scope (passed as a parameter to `Scope.initialize`).

**The `Scope` object**

```
class Scope

  def initialize(scope)
    @scope = scope
  end

  def resolve
    # Return a modified scope.
  end
end
```

**The controller**

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  def show
    foos = Scope.new(Foo.some_foos).resolve
    respond_with foos
  end
end
```

**The test**

```
it "does something" do
  allow_any_instance_of(Scope).to receive(:resolve).and_return(???.scope)
  get :show
  # Do some assertions.
end
```

What do I need to put where the `???` are in order to stub the `resolve` method on any instance of `Scope` to return the original scope that it was created with?

I'm using Rspec 3.4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you will want to create a attribute reader on Scope so that you can access `@scope` without using `instance_variable_get`:

```
class Scope

  attr_reader :scope

  def initialize(scope)
    @scope = scope
  end

  def resolve
    # Return a modified scope.
  end
end
```

If you use block implementation the receiver is passed as the first arg:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Scope).to receive(:resolve) do |s|
  s.scope
end
```

However using `allow_any_instance_of` is strongly discouraged and usually a sign that your tests are poking around too much in how your controllers do their job instead of actually [testing their behavior in a future proof way](https://everydayrails.com/2016/08/29/replace-rspec-controller-tests.html).

I would instead use a unit test which tests `Scope` and request specs which tests the controller in conjunction with feature specs. This is how I test applications that use Pundit and is a robust strategy.